# active admin / formtastic , add all inputs in a single block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, formtastic

A report, has_many answers, and an answer belongs_to report. The nested form is displayed and works, but for the 5 answers I have

Add Answer

Answer **__**

Add Answer

Answer **__**

[next 3]

How can i group them in one single block with title "Add Answer", and 5 inputs ?

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "New Report" do 
      f.input :title
      f.input :type
      f.input :help_text
      f.input :text_box_present
      f.input :text_box_default
      f.input :template_id
    end

    f.inputs "ADD Answers", for: :answers do |a|
      a.input :text, label: "Answer", required: false
    end
    f.actions  
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, this is some elegant stuff that active admin and formtastic provides for nested attributes

```
f.inputs "Answers"  do
  f.has_many :answers do |a|
    a.input :text, label: "Answer", required: false
  end 
end
```

It will auto add a delete/add button with javascript, for adding multiple answers